# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Release is unable to boot and lands in a blank screen after fresh installation in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04

Using latest download image of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS stable release in Virtual Box with fixed storage of 80 gb and 4 gb RAM installs properly with no errors , but in first boot it lands in a blank screen prompting no error neither taking to Desktop.

Did performed the installation multiple times to find the same observation. Any one facing the similar error and any workaround ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this error myself. Turn off the VM by sending the shutdown signal, go to the settings and up the Video Memory to the max and try it again. I believe that you are trying to run Ubuntu while in full screen mode but the given video memory is not enough to run it.

Comment: Yes It works perfect , increased Video memory to 128 Mb which is max.

Answer (score 5):

Switching from full screen to scaled mode and then back to full screen allowed me to see my guest's screen.

**Background**

I had already set the video memory to 128 MBs, but was getting a blank screen in full screen mode anyway. I have an ultrawide monitor and had installed the guest extensions so that I could use the full resolution (2560x1080) which was fine before rebooting the guest. Following a reboot or shutdown+boot, I was getting a blank screen after the spinning Ubuntu loading screen. I discovered that switching VirtualBox between modes would workaround the issue. Hopefully Oracle is able to fix this, seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is more than likely your Video Memory setting. After setting up the name of the machine, before you start it and select the ubuntu image to boot from, please go into Settings, then Display, and under the "Screen" tab, increase the default Video Memory setting to 128mb by sliding the bar to the right. The default setting is just not enough.

Answer (score 0):

VBox 6.1.14 now on MacBook Pro host with Xubuntu 20.04 guest.  still have this issue under VMSVGA mode.  Setting video memory to 128MB does not help.  My resolution is 2048x1280.  As Jeremy suggested, switching from full screen mode to scale mode and back brings the display normal.  Another option, which saves the steps of switching to scale mode, is to use VBoxVGA mode, which brings up Xubuntu's display outright.  No direct 3D under VBoxVGA I think, but who cares given 3D support under VBox is poor anyway, and the guest runs faster with VBoxVGA.

Comment: I had the same blank screen problem (running Ubuntu 20.04) on Windows - switching the graphics controller to VBoxSVGA solved the problem - maxing the video memory made no difference.